# What are RAM Versions?

Tags: memory

While I was looking at the RAM compatibility list in MSI's website, i see a version number beside the RAM's PN as seen in the picture:

[image: Ram Versions]

What does that version number mean? Is it a physical revision of the RAM? How do I determine the version of the RAM that I am going to buy? Will a different version of the RAM cause it not to work with the motherboard?

Comment: That list of memory are the ones the motherboard manufacturer has tested to be compatible, does not mean many others are not. The version number states which IC type is used on that specific memory stick>>>https://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=178400

Comment: Thanks! I will look more into IC types